# App Crash when i call request with Alamofire 5.6.2 for some device

Tags: swift, alamofire

my request is like ths

```
 AF.request(request).validate(statusCode: 200...500).responseJSON { response in
```

This is the crash log from TestFlight

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
 <br>0   CoreFoundation                 0x1993badc0 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
 <br>1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x1adf177a8 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
 <br>2   Foundation                     0x19a67d61c +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 316 (NSJSONSerialization.m:0)
 <br>3    GO_Dev                        0x100c59aec closure #1 in closure #1 in AutoSyncLoginVC.callSyncLoginAPI(username:password:) + 628 (AutoSyncLoginVC.swift:343)
 <br>4    GO_Dev                        0x100d9611c closure #1 in ApiManagerV2.requestWith(apiname:body:parameter:mainIP:method:success:failure:) + 2064 (ApiManager.swift:0)
 <br>5   Alamofire                      0x10219a544 partial apply for specialized closure #2 in closure #2 in closure #3 in closure #1 in DownloadRequest._response<A>(queue:responseSerializer:completionHandler:) + 48
 <br>6   Alamofire                      0x10212ddd0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

Comment: Share maybe the code of `AutoSyncLoginVC.callSyncLoginAPI(username:password:)`? Are you using bad parameters?

Comment: It seems the crash is happening inside `+[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]`, so your JSON might contain invalid data. It's also possible a numeric value overflows is the crash happens on a 32 bit device. However, without seeing the actual JSON that's causing the crash, it's impossible to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This crash is likely occurring due to the parameters passed through `JSONSerialization`, as not all Swift values are convertible to JSON using that class. I suggest you either use Alamofire's `ParameterEncoder` to encode `Encodable` parameter values, or check `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject` before attempting to encode your parameters.